# How to reference an iOS C++ project into an iOS C# app

Tags: xamarin.ios

I created an Android C++ project in VS2017,
referenced the Android C++ project in the C# Android app
and it works fine (it can interop to the C methods from C#).

I'm trying to do the same with iOS.
The C++ iOS project builds fine (using vcremote), but it can not be referenced from the C# iOS project (error message below). This seems to be a limitation of the UI. Is it supported ? If not, what is the workaround ?

The samples on the doc website are only about referencing the iOS C++ project in a C++ iOS app project, not a C# iOS app project.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to 'Comp.AppLib.Native.iOS' could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe these will help you? [Referencing Native Libraries in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/native-interop) and [CALLING C/C++ LIBRARIES FROM XAMARIN CODE](https://kerry.lothrop.de/c-libraries/)

Comment: Ty but I already know these. 1st one requires a compiled fat lib. 2nd one is just c#/C++ interop and is out of question scope. I'm trying to simplify my toolchain.